# Replacing blank spaces with "NULL" string

Tags: php

I am trying to make a form which includes some text inputs, select inputs, and date inputs in which some inputs are optional. So, if someone leaves these inputs blank and submits, I want "NULL" to be entered in mysql database instead of ' '.

Following is a part of my code that i tried:

```
   <?php

 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','abcdef','trademarkfilingproject');

error_reporting(1);


 $Preference2 = 'Null';

 if(!$con)
    { 
        echo "Not Connected To Server";
    }
 else{

    $Department = $_POST['department'];
    $Classs = $_POST['classs'];
    $Preference1 = $_POST['preference1'];

    function replaceWithNull(&$Preference2)
    {
    if (empty($Preference2) || $Preference2 == ' ') {
        $Preference2 = "NULL";
    }  
    }
    array_walk($_POST, "replaceWithNull");


    $Preference3 = '';
    $Preference4 = '';
    $Preference5 ='';
    $Goods = $_POST['goodsnservice'];
    $Mark = $_POST['mark'];
    $MarkYesWhen = $_POST['yeswhen'];
    $MarkYesCountry = $_POST['yescountry'];
    $MarkNoWhen = ''; 
    $MarkNoCountry = ''; 
    $MarkAppliedCountry = $_POST['markappliedcountry'];

    //echo $_POST['prefer1'];  

    //print_r($_POST['yescountry']); die();


$sql = "INSERT INTO requestor (Department,Class,Preference_One,Preference_Two,Preference_Three,Preference_Four,Preference_Five,Goods_Services,Mark_In_Use,Mark_Yes_When,Mark_Yes_Country,Mark_No_When,Mark_No_Country,Mark_Applied_Country) VALUES('$Department','$Classs','$Preference1','$Preference2','$Preference3','$Preference4','$Preference5','$Goods','$Mark','$MarkYesWhen','$MarkYesCountry','$MarkNoWhen','$MarkNoCountry','$MarkAppliedCountry')";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

header("refresh:1 ; url=success.html");

 }
?>
```

If i use the above code, preference 2 gets "NULL" if empty. But, If the input is not blank i am trying to use the code below:

```
function replaceWithNull(&$Preference2)
    {
    if (empty($Preference2) || $Preference2 == ' ') {
        $Preference2 = "NULL";
    }
        else {
            $Preference2 = $_POST['preference2'];
        }

    }
    array_walk($_POST, "replaceWithNull");
```

[image: This is the structure of my record]

[image: If I use the code(without else statement), I get the NULL value inserted in mysql. When I include the else statement, my nothing gets inserted in my record.]

Below is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="\images\trademark_icon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">


</head>
<style>

.error {color: #FF0000;}


#markyes {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#markno {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

input[value="yes"]:checked ~ #markyes {
    display: block;
}

input[value="no"]:checked ~ #markno {
    display: block;
}


input[type=text], select {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


input[type=button] {
    width: 10%;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    outline: 2px black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px 40px;
}

body{
background-image: url("images/bg-01.jpg");
background-repeat:repeat;
z-index:1;
}

.form-title {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto;
  padding:50;
}

.herologo {
    hight:70px; 
    width:60px;
    background-position: top-left;
    float:left;
}
</style>
<body>

<h2 ><img src="images/hero_logo.png" class="herologo" ><span class="form-title">Trademark Filing Application</span></h2><br>

<div>
<p style="padding-left:20px"><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

  <form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- Department  -->

    <b>Select Department:</b><span class="error"> *</span>
    <select id="dept" name="department" required>
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
      <option value="ceo">CEO Office</option>
      <option value="global">Global</option>
      <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
      <option value="parts">Parts</option>

    </select>
    <br><br><br>

    <!-- Class  -->

    <b>Select Class:</b><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="wordradio" name="classs" value="Word" required>Word
    <input type="radio" id="deviceradio" name="classs" value="Device" style="margin-left:20px">Device
    <input type="radio" id="logoradio" name="classs" value="Logo" style="margin-left:20px">Logo
    <input type="radio" id="soundradio" name="classs" value="Sound" style="margin-left:20px">Sound
    <input type="radio" id="taglineradio" name="classs" value="Tagline" style="margin-left:20px">Tagline
    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Preferences  -->


    <b>Enter Preference(s):</b><br>
    1. <input type="text" id="pref1" name="preference1" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 1" required>
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn1" name="files[]" multiple="" required>
    <span class="error">*</span>
    <br>

    2. <input type="text" id="pref2" name="preference2" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 2">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn2" name="files[]" multiple="" >

    <br>
    3. <input type="text" id="pref3" name="preference3" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 3">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn3" name="files[]" multiple="" >

    <br>
    4. <input type="text" id="pref4" name="preference4" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 4">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn4" name="files[]" multiple="" >

    <br>
    5. <input type="text" id="pref5" name="preference5" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 5">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn5" name="files[]" multiple="" >

    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Goods and Services  -->


    <b>Enter The Types of Goods & Services :</b><span class="error"> *</span>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="goodss" name="goodsnservice" placeholder="Select the type of Goods and Services" required>

    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Mark in Use?  -->

   <b>Is Mark In Use?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="marky" name="mark" value="yes" onclick="disableNo()" required>Yes


    <!-- Mark in Use?: YES  -->


    <div id="markyes" class="show-hide" style="background-color:white;width:600px ;margin-left:40px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:5px"><br>
    <b>When Did You Use It?</b>
    <input type="date" name="yeswhen" style="margin-left:10px" id="markyesdate" required><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>

    <b>Where Did You Use It?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>
    <select name="yescountry[]" style="width:20%" id="markyescountry" multiple required>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
             ...
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select><br><br>

            <b>Proof Of First Use:</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>
    <input type="file" id="markyesproof" name="files[]" value="Upload one or more files" multiple="" required>
    </div><br>


            <!-- Mark in Use?: NO  -->


    <input type="radio" name="mark" value="no" onclick="disableYes()" >No<br>
    <div id="markno" class="show-hide" style="background-color:white;width:600px ;margin-left:40px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:5px"><br>
    <b>When Are You Expected To Use It?</b>
    <input type="date" name="nowhen" style="margin-left:10px" id="marknodate" required><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>

    <b>Where will You Use It?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>
    <select name="nocountry[]" style="width:20%" id="marknocountry" multiple required>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
          ...
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select><br><br>

    </div><br>


            <!-- Mark Applied Country  -->


    <b style="text-height:50%">Mark Applied Country:</b><br>
    <select name="markappliedcountry[]" style="width:20%" multiple >
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
         ...
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select><br><br>

    <br><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<script>
function disableNo() {
    document.getElementById("marknocountry").required = false; 
    document.getElementById("marknodate").required = false;      
}

function disableYes() {
    document.getElementById("markyescountry").required = false; 
    document.getElementById("markyesdate").required = false;
    document.getElementById("markyesproof").required = false;       
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use built-in constant [NULL](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) all DB drivers understand them and will work if the required columns in Table definition is nullable.

Comment: @anand Nishant specifically wants to insert `"NULL"` string.

Comment: @anand structure of my record is already that way. IsNull is checked and Default is Null, still submitting a blank field leaves the space blank, but I want "null" string to be entered instead.

Comment: @NishantSharma I have upvoted Aniket answer if you want "NULL" in string put it in quotes and if it's the columns are string holding datatypes like CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT etc then it would work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"'NULL'"` in place of `"NULL"`. This will insert `"NULL"` string at desired place. Basically `$Preference2 = "NULL";` should be `$Preference2 = "'NULL'";`

What you are doing is this:

```
insert into myTb (val) values (NULL);
```

What you should be doing is:

```
insert into myTb (val) values ('NULL');
```

Comment: can you share your email id. I think I will be able to explain my problem more clearly.

Comment: @NishantSharma You can update the question if you want.

Comment: @NishantSharma You forgot to explain what is going wrong with the code.

Comment: I want that my code inputs Null/None string instead of empty spaces of preference2/3/4/5, markyescountry,markyesproof,markyeswhen,marknocountry,markno when. Because these are optional fields in the form. I am new to web development.

Comment: @NishantSharma Updating `$Preference2 = "NULL";` to `$Preference2 = "'NULL'";` should solve the problem.

Comment: Using "NULL" and " 'NULL' " gave me same output as shown in 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/415zj.png (NULL that I've encircled in blue). But even if I enter something in the preference 2 text field, I get the same "Null" as output. That's a problem. If i modify my code as: 
    if (empty($Preference2) || $Preference2 == ' ') {
        $Preference2 = "NULL";
    }
        else {
            $Preference2 = $_POST['preference2'];
        }

    }
    array_walk($_POST, "replaceWithNull");                                               Nothing gets inserted in my sql record

Comment: @NishantSharma Paste [this](https://pastebin.com/BvYyeatL) code into your else statement.

Comment: @NishantSharma Also keep in mind that no matter that you are using `mysqli_*` your script is vulnerable to sql injections. DON'T USE IT IN PRODUCTION OR SELL THIS CODE TO CONSUMER BEFORE FIXING THE ISSUE.

Comment: I've pasted your code in my else statement. It's Not working. Now no data is being inserted in the records. Also, I'm doing an internship, and this is just a project given to me. I'm new to web development and doing this for the first time that's why I'm facing such problems.

Comment: still the same bro, nothing is getting inserted in my record.

Comment: @NishantSharma Did you change the password and database name. I unknowingly posted the username, password, and db name that I used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @NishantSharma I am really sorry, I can't help it more. The code that I have posted works on my machine.

Comment: If you can share your email id, than I can share my whole folder with you through google drive, including my exported sql file. Mine is nishant.sharma.14cse@bml.edu.in

Comment: you can delete it now